# Cython passing extension modules to python reults in to_py_call_code error

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am just starting to get familiar with Cython, trying to wrap some class from a C++ library to Python methods and classes. What I do not really understand is how to pass the these extension modules into python world.

Here is the code snippet from my `pyx` file which tries to expose c++ classes and methods:

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Demuxer.cpp, SharedUtil.cpp, ffmpeg_tpl.c, tpl.c
# distutils: libraries = spam eggs
# distutils: include_dirs = /opt/food/include

from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref

cdef extern from "Demuxer.h":
    cdef cppclass DemuxPkt:
        int streamID
        int tb_num
        int tb_den
        bint splitPoint     
        int ts
        int duration 
        unsigned char* data
        DemuxPkt()
    int initDemuxWithFileImpl(char*)
    int getNextChunkImpl(DemuxPkt*)
```

And the following is the code snippet that tries to wrap them into python world

```
cdef class Demuxer:

    def __cinit__(self, fname, stream=None, length=None):
        #if stream is not None and length is not None:
         #   initDemuxWithFileImpl(stream, length)
        #else:
        initDemuxWithFileImpl(fname)

    cpdef getNextChunk(self):
        cdef DemuxPacket _dpkt = DemuxPacket()
        getNextChunkImpl(_dpkt._thisptr) # Is this correct??
        return _dpkt


cdef class DemuxPacket(object):

    """A packet of encoded data 
    """
    cdef DemuxPkt* _thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, flag):
        #if flag is _cinit_bypass_sentinel:
        #    return
        self._thisptr = new DemuxPkt()
        if self._thisptr == NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self._thisptr != NULL:
            del self._thisptr

    def __call__(self):
        return deref(self._thisptr)()

    cpdef long getMillisecondsTs(self):
        return (self._thisptr.ts*self._thisptr.tb_num)/(self._thisptr.tb_den/1000)

    cpdef long getMillisecondsDuration(self):
        return (self._thisptr.duration*self.struct.tb_num)/(self._thisptr.tb_den/1000)
```

However, when I run cython the following errors appear:

```
AttributeError: 'ErrorType' object has no attribute 'to_py_call_code'
```

I have no idea about the message and do not know how to advance. The version of Cython that I use is 0.25.2 on Ubuntu 14.0.4.

Any suggestions are appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in `__call__`. You try to use `DemuxPkt::operator()` but you haven't told Cython about it. Add it to the `cppclass` definition:

```
cdef extern from "Demuxer.h":
    cdef cppclass DemuxPkt:
        # .. everything else unchanged
        int operator()()
```

I've guessed that the return type is `int`. Obviously this may not be true, so change it to match the real return type.